# How to do the new sweep attack in minecraft 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I wanted to know how to do the new sweep attack in Minecraft 1.9 update. What are the controls for it?

Comment: Go to Option and change your crosshair so you can see "attack delay timer" , that will help you to see when your power is full :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do the sweep attack, you must be in 1.9 (obviously) and be standing still or holding shift. The attack cool down must also be full in order to do a sweep attack. Sprinting and attacking at the same time will stop you from being able to do a sweep attack.

Comment: I have tested sweeps on the move by splitting a big slime into a hoard of the smallest. I got several sweeps while walking but none for running.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into your Minecraft `settings`, and then go to `video settings`, and then their should be a setting called: `ATTACK Indicator`.  Click this until it shows up as `On`. Once it shows up as on, close your settings and get back into your game.

If you click with a weapon, you will see a little sword on your cross-hair(the thing in the middle of your screen)this is the cool-down for swinging a sword. It will fill up after you swing, and once it fills up completely, you can swing your sword again. you can swing your sword while the cool-down is happening, but it will NOT do the sweep unless it is cooled down all the way.

Long story short, just swing your sword at the enemy and it will do the sweep attack. xD

Answer (score 0):

You just attack as normal. I believe there is a cool down and/or a reduced range as it does not happen every time, however with slowed deliberate strikes I can get a sweep every time using a sword. I am not sure if it is possible with other weapons.

Edit:
You also need to be striking a mob.

Answer (score -2):

If you tap the attack button, you do a traditional attack.  If you hold the attack button down, you do a slower (but more powerful) attack.

Comment: I only ever tap the mouse buttons, and even loaded up Mincraft to test it and sure enough a is good enough to get a sweep.

Comment: Odd.  I found that I'd consistently sweep with a slightly longer mouse click and hold.  A 1-frame click would just do the normal attack.  Maybe I have a dodgy mouse. :)

Comment: The length of the click does not matter, but the time between does.